# What is the correct way to reference image files from a header file that is referenced by multiple .html/.php files in different sub directories?

Tags: php, html

I have my header file for my website and a bunch of images that are inside the header that I want to link to various pages within the website.

I'm currently referencing the images from within the header file like this:

```
<header>
    <div id="menu">
    <div class="table">
        <ul id="horizontal-list">
            <li><a href="../home page/home.php">            <img src="../home page/home.png"            alt="Home Page"         width=150                                   /></a></li>
            <li><a href="../dashboard page/dashboard.php">  <img src="../dashboard page/dashboard.png"  alt="User Dashboard"    width=150   style="padding-left: 35px;"     /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

The problem with this approach, since those file paths are relative, they don't work if I reference the header file from a sub directory that upon traversing those relative file paths, it's unable to find the files located.

Since I have my web pages all inside different directories, using this approach means that while the files in one directory will be able to find the images for the header file perfectly ok, the web pages inside another directory aren't able to find the images.

I tried changing my relative file paths to absolute file paths like so:

change

```
"../home page/home.php"
"../home page/home.png"
```

to

```
"C:/xampp/htdocs/login/website php version/home page/home.php"
"C:/xampp/htdocs/login/website php version/home page/home.png"
```

but this didn't work either

Comment: Use a slash `/` to start from the document root. `<img src="/...`, `<a href="/...`

Comment: worked great! Looks like there's inconsistency between where `/` starts when doing `include` and where `/` starts when referencing `src`

Comment: Not sure if `/` is available/works the same way when using Windows, but for `include`/`require` on Linux/Unix systems this is the root/topmost file path, like `/var/www/html/includes`. Yes, different from `src`/`href`

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the insight and responses

Comment: Also note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.